# Function to add string to an excel cell upon if condition on the same cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

How can I write a formula in a cell to append an `_` to the end of the string existing in the cell, if the currently existing string matches a string in another column?

Comment: You'll need to use the [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel) event.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: What have you tried? There are many ways to do it. One being `=IF(COUNTIF(A1:A10,B1)>0,B1&"_","")`?

Comment: As a workaround,I added a new column and used the following formula: 

=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(UPPER([@[Column name in source]]);Supplements!A:A;0));[@[Column name in source]];CONCATENATE([@[Column name in source]];"_"))

It does what I want, but my question is whether or not I can do it on the same column.

Answer (score 0):

Screenshots refer:

**Method 1**

*(Not as precise, but parsimonious / robust)*

```
=MATCH(Table1[column name in source]&"*",Supplements,0)
```

[image: Method 1]

---

**Method 2**

*Precise; with Office 365 function can be shortened/condensed using let function but this is not necessity)*

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(Table1[column name in source],Supplements,0),MATCH(Table1[column name in source]&"_",Supplements,0))
```

[image: Method 2]

---